# Blazor Virtualize component breaks on horizontal scroll

Tags: blazor

I have a basic `<table>` element, and in it's body I used the `<Virtualize>` component for better row rendering performance. The problem comes when scrolling on the horizontal axis. If the scroll position is not at 0, the rows won't render. Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you upgraded to .NET 6? This bug should have been fixed: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/37587